# Making Input and Output files in C language according to the code?

Tags: c, file-io

This is a first formal C competition I am going through .In the last years paper they had- Specified something called aromatic number and told to find those .I wrote the code and it works well but I am not able to understand these instructions about input and output and how to code them in C for Windows.
[image: From the previous paper]

I am aware about reading one letter from a file and writing it using fopen() and fprintf and fscanf. But these are  letters written in different lines how to extract them as variables from in1.dat and print them in out1.dat?

Means I know

```
 int main()
{
   int n;
   FILE *fptr;
   if ((fptr=fopen("D:\\program.dat","r"))==NULL){
       printf("Error! opening file");
       exit(1);         /* Program exits if file pointer returns NULL. */
   }
   fscanf(fptr,"%d",&n);
   printf("Value of n=%d",n+n); 
   fclose(fptr);   
   getch();
}
```

Which scans the first value in the 1st line .But they ask for multiple lines(3 in sample input) how to do them?

Comment: Do you not know about [`for` loops](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm)?

Comment: Errors belong on stderr: `char *path=argv[1]; if((fptr=fopen(path))==NULL){ perror(path); exit(1);}`

Comment: @ChronoKitsune they don't work here

Comment: I tried    :  while(fscanf(fptr,"%d",&n)!=EOF);
  {
   printf("Value of n= %d \n" ,n); 
  
   }   but it just returns the last number of the file

Comment: What do you mean `don't work here ` ?

Comment: I mean I tried putting them but I get the some output.

Comment: @ShivamPatel  Did it worked ?

Comment: no please help ,I am getting confused !  I wrote
while(fscanf(fptr,"%d",&n)!=EOF);
  {
   fscanf(fptr,"%d",&n);                               
   printf("Value of n= %d \n" ,n); 
  
   } 
it is just giving the last input whats wrong?

Comment: @ShivamPatel Please see answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84272/discussion-between-ameycu-and-shivam-patel).

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like This:

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        FILE *in,*out;
        int num;
        char line[512],aronum[20];
        in = fopen("in.dat", "r");
        out = fopen("out.dat","w");
        fgets(line, 512, in); //to get number of test cases
        sscanf (line, "%d",&num);

        while((fgets(line, 512, in) != NULL) && (num--))
        {
             sscanf (line, "%s",&aronum);
             fprintf(out,"%d",calc(aronum)); //use `calc` func to return int ans.

        }

        fclose(in);
        fclose(out);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: calc is a function which performs the required calculation to return the result  .i.e the decimal value of the aromatic number.

Comment: Is this function defined in c?

Comment: nope. its implementation will be related to conversion of aromatic numbers to decimal values  but i guess the problem here is how to read multiple lines input from a file and output it in a file :)

Answer (score 0):

```
fscanf(fptr,"%d",&n);
printf("Value of n=%d",n+n);
```

Instead do like this -

```
while(fscanf(fptr,"%d",&n))
{
   printf("Value of n=%d",n+n); //But notice here with every iteration n will be over-written.
}
```

This will stop at the first conversion failure or end of the file.And then inside this loop you can write into output file .